Stability of fixed points in a 2D discrete time dynamical system
I am studying the stability of fixed points in the Henon map for a project, and I have a question regarding it. The Henon map we are studying is given by:
\begin{align*} x_{n+1}&=1+y_n-\alpha x_n^2 \\ y_{n+1}&=\beta x_n, \hspace{1in} \alpha>0, |\beta|<1
\end{align*}
I found the period one fixed points (there are two of them) and was able to derive some conditions on $\alpha$ for existence. Each fixed point is stable if the associated eigenvalues are less than 1 in magnitude. The fixed points I have are:
$$(x_1,y_1)=\Big(\frac{-(1-\beta)+\sqrt{(1-\beta)^2+4\alpha}}{2\alpha}, \frac{-\beta(1-\beta)+\beta\sqrt{(1-\beta)^2+4\alpha}}{2\alpha}\Big)$$
$$(x_2,y_2)=\Big(\frac{-(1-\beta)-\sqrt{(1-\beta)^2+4\alpha}}{2\alpha}, \frac{-\beta(1-\beta)-\beta\sqrt{(1-\beta)^2+4\alpha}}{2\alpha}\Big)$$
and the eigenvalues are $\lambda_{1,2} =-\alpha x \pm\sqrt{\alpha^2 x^2+\beta}$. Here is my question:
Since each fixed point has 2 eigenvalues, how do we determine stability? Do we do so by looking at $|\lambda_1\lambda_2|<1$ or do we check that $|\lambda_1|<1$ and $|\lambda_2|<1$? Everything I look up or read about talks about stability of equilibrium points in continuous time dynamical systems, and the analysis is the equilibrium is stable if both eigenvalues are real and negative. I haven’t found anything for discrete maps.
